# Can't calculate time in javascript

Tags: javascript, time

I'm trying to do when you press the cat or cube button, javascript count the time, and if time is 2 seconds or more, alert saying Finished time.
Here is a piece of the code, just for the cat button.

```
catbutton.onclick=function() {catfunction()};
function catfunction(){
    if (randomElement=="cat1.jpg" || randomElement=="cat2.jpg"){
        x++;
        randomElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
        console.log(randomElement)
        console.log(randomElement)
        image.src=(randomElement);
        startTime = new Date();
        endTime = new Date();
        var time = endTime - startTime;
        if (timeDiff>2000){
            alert('Finished time')
            }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: `timestart=0; timeend=0; catbutton.onmousedown=function(){timestart=new Date()}  catbutton.onmouseup=function(){timeend=new Date(); timeend-timestart>2000 && alert('Finished time');}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `setTimeout()` for this problem.

Check out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) for details.

```
function catfunction() {
  // ...
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Finished time');
  }, 2000);
}
```

If you want to add/subtract seconds with Date Object, use `getTime()` method which returns the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch.
Here's an example

```
var now = new Date();
var afterTenSeconds = new Date(now.getTime() + 1000 * 10)
console.log(afterTenSeconds);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use console.time api

```
console.time("CatFnTime");
enter code here what you want to measure
console.timeEnd("CatFnTime");
```